# Link scrolling to moving an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

recently, on a wide range of pages, I've seen objects moving on the screen accordingly to scrolling up or down the site. I have searched the forum, but I haven't found a solution to this yet. Is there a jQuery Plugin to achieve this?

[Example](http://www.guyvernes.com/)
(flying cloud guy on the very bottom)

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to the left position being changed when amount you've scrolled changes: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/hBHFz/1/.

```
var elem = $("#a"),   // cache for speed
    body = $("body");

$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    elem.css("left", body.scrollTop()); // set left to amount scrolled
});
```